# Setting up a basic plugin with gradle

Tags: elasticsearch, gradle, build.gradle, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm trying to setup a basic elasticsearch plugin with gradle that follows [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/plugins/examples/script-expert-scoring) example. I realized the build.gradle file in the repo is not sufficient (for some reason) so this is my current `build.gradle` file

```
 plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath "org.elasticsearch.gradle:build-tools:6.5.4"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'elasticsearch.esplugin'

esplugin {
    name 'script-expert-scoring'
    description 'An example script engine to use low level Lucene internals for expert scoring'
    classname 'org.elasticsearch.example.expertscript.ExpertScriptPlugin'
    licenseFile rootProject.file('licenses/APACHE-LICENSE-2.0.txt')
    noticeFile rootProject.file('NOTICE.txt')
}

unitTest.enabled = false
```

I added the classpath dependency myself because I realized I probably need it. But now I'm getting an error saying

> cannot find method classpath() for arguments [org.elasticsearch.gradle:build-tools:6.5.4]

Am I missing something or is this completely wrong?

Answer (score 2):

try to put it inside a buildscript block like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.elasticsearch.gradle:build-tools:6.5.4"
    }
}
```

[Here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-esplugin-replace-change-disable-integtestcluster-wait-task/115006/2) is a better example, or [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/writing-your-own-ingest-processor-for-elasticsearch) if you want a more complete approach.